# I am getting nothing when I try to access a variable of one function in another function in CodeIgniter 4?

Tags: model-view-controller, codeigniter-4

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers\AdminControllers;
use App\Controllers\BaseController;
use App\Models\AdminModels\CategoryModel;    


class ProductController extends BaseController{
       
    public $my_variable;
    
    public function index(){ 

        $data['cat_list'] = $this->cat_obj->select(array('cat_id','cat_name'))->where('cat_status', 1)->findAll();

        $this->my_variable = "test";
        return view('admin/index',$data);   
    
    }

    public function insert(){
        echo($this->my_variable);
        return view('admin/productadd', $data);
    }
  

}
```

I am not getting value.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: I got it.... it should be,

`public function insert(){
      $this->index();
        echo($this->my_variable);
        return view('admin/productadd', $data);
    }`

Comment: ...or you could fill `$my_variable` in a `__construct()`-call, as all the other stuff in `index()` is not needed. Or use a constant.

Comment: @SimonWeber actually my data is coming from the index method... so its not possible to use in constructor... is there any other way ?

Comment: There are a lot of ways, which to take depends on the type of data `$my_variable` holds and where it does come from.